# Manually calculated -3dB cut off frequency differs from the simulated value

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

I have been trying to do experiments with a differential BJT pair.

As the output resistance for the common emitter configuration is R_c (1k), instead of finding the capacitance, I attached a 1pF capacitor. I wanted to find the cut-off frequency of this circuit instead of the one without it.

This is expected to be similar to a single pole system.

My theoretical bandwidth is 1/RC but from the simulation I got about 26MHz.

Is the variation due to the capacitance or some mistake I made while calculating?

[image: Circuit]

[image]

Comment: You need to account for the transistor's resitances, too, and capacitances -- 1p is quite close to their internal parasitics.

Comment: yea , regarding the resistance: output resistance of a CE config is Rc right? is there any other resistance?       And Capacitance: If I add a load capacitance such that the effective output capacitance would close to the load capacitance? Thats what i though , please correct me if am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @aconcerned citizen   :what about 1000p? resistance , is it available in data sheet? whats that resistance called? internal resistance but collector?

Comment: anyway thanks , i will experiment with different values and will check again.

Comment: The output resistance is `ro||Rc` (without caps), which may be approximated by `Rc` in ideal conditions, but you are not using ideal elements, are you? Try using generic NPNs, you may get closer to what you expect, but even then, if what you expect is for the output resistance to be `Rc`, then you need to use the equivalent small signal schematic for the transistor (input resistance, controlled current source, output resistance, with or without parallel capacitor), not an actual transistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [2N2222 data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/296640.pdf): -

[image]

1 kΩ and 1 pF produce a 3 dB point of 159 MHz but, when you factor in the typical capacitance of the actual transistor it's going to be below 20 MHz.

You should also take into account the transition frequency too. At 250 MHz (see above) the transistor's β will be unity. At 25 MHz the β will be only 10 and this makes a poor choice if in fact you need gain at tens of MHz.